# Keep object from session soped to view scoped

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

When I pass a object  from session scoped to view scoped the values ​​are lost,How Can I solve this problem? I want to keep the same values in the viewScoped

**First controller:**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class CargaLaboralController {

 public Solicitud selected;

 //logic with selected

}
```

**Page:**

```
<ui:param value="#{cargaLaboralController.selected}" name="selected"></ui:param>
                      <p:commandButton value="Continuar" icon="ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e" ajax="false" action="#{generarCriController.cargarCertificadoImbobiliario(selected)}">
```

**Second controller:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class GenerarCriController {
private Solicitud selected = new Solicitud();

public String  cargarCertificadoImbobiliario(Solicitud selected) {
        this.selected=selected;
//etc
  return "NextPage"
 }
```

Comment: More context of `<ui:param>` would be helpful. Regardless, what if you use `<c:set var="selected" value="#{cargaLaboralController.selected}" />` instead?

Comment: the result is the same

Comment: Okay. Apparently your session scoped bean is actually not session scoped. Is the scope annotation imported from the right package?

Comment: the  import is javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped,when I use session scoped in my second controlled work well,but with viewscoped doesn't work

Comment: Right, I believe you misidentified the problem. The value is not lost during parameter passing. It's lost during navigation. As evidence, put a debug breakpoint (or poor man's `System.out.println()`) right before the return statement in `cargarCertificadoImbobiliario()` method and check the value of `selected` variable. It should be non-null. 
Is this true?